# How to set background color in IntelliJ for all panels

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, color-scheme

I'm trying to customize the colors of my scheme but I'm not getting the result I want on Intelli J.

I would like each panel to be the same shade of color and opacity.
As you can see in the image, I would like the terminal and editor to be the same as the panel on the top left (empty project)

[image]

Do you know if this is possible? thank you all.

Comment: All of them are separate settings. See https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes-extras.html#adding-a-custom-editor-scheme

Comment: And the appropriate settings: [Editor background](https://i.imgur.com/Bh4XK0E.png), [Terminal background](https://i.imgur.com/w5ePquu.png),

Comment: Thank you! I tried the appropriate settings and work very good!